# Cannot deploy web service in GlassFish using together @WebserviceProvider and @Stateless

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I tried to deploy in GlassFish JAX-WS web service,
Here is a snippet of class were the web service is defined. Pay attention that I implemented Provider interface on EJB endpoint.

```
@Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJBWS")
@WebServiceProvider(
    portName = "HelloWorldWSPort", 
    serviceName = "HelloWorldWSService", 
    targetNamespace = "http://ivan.com/",
    wsdlLocation ="HelloWorldEJBProvider.wsdl")

@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)

public class HelloWorldEJBWS implements Provider<Source> {

public Source invoke(final Source inRequestMessage) {

    ...
}   
}
```

The problem is about the deploying the service in GlassFish (3.1.2.2) . F.

[#|2012-09-08T16:39:15.682-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.**container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers**|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB HelloWorldEJBWS: [java:global/JAX-WS_GreetingEJBMutualAuthProvider/HelloWorldEJBWS, java:global/JAX-WS_GreetingEJBMutualAuthProvider/HelloWorldEJBWS!javax.xml.ws.Provider]|#]

[#|2012-09-08T16:39:15.792-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
 JAX-WS_GreetingEJBMutualAuthProvider  listening at address at **http://ABRAMOV1:8088/HelloWorldWSService/com.ivan.wsejb.provider.HelloWorldEJBWS**|#]

Even it shows the endpoint is deployed - is not . I can't reach this endpoint and it is not shown in GlassFish console.

For comparison I provide the log when I deployed the service using @WebService but not @WebServiceProvider

[#|2012-09-08T16:41:50.514-0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed
 JAX-WS_GreetingEJBMutualAuth  listening at address at **http://ABRAMOV1:8088/HelloWorldEJBWSService/HelloWorldEJBWS|#]**

In this case endpoint deployed correctly and everything is working fine.

Here is snipped of the code when I apply  @WebService

```
@Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJBWS")
@WebService()
public class HelloWorldEJBWS {

public String hello(final String inMessage) {
    ...
}
```

}

Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I did everything right but was mislead by GlassFish. It could be a a bug...
When I deploy web service with endpoint implemented as servlet (second case) in the console I can see endpoint, but in case with endpoint implemented as EJB the endpoint did not appear in the console. But I could access the WSDL with a link `http://localhost:8088/HelloWorldWSService/com.ivan.wsejb.provider.HelloWorldEJBWS?wsdl`  and ultimately tested web service with the client